# Should I mount garage door hardware to studs through drywall, or directly to stud?

Tags: drywall, doors, garage, patching-drywall, garage-door

I'm having my garage doors replaced next week and I'm debating whether to install drywall before the installation or after.

The wall that the garage doors are on is currently not insulated or drywalled (same deal with another adjacent exterior-only wall). I've already run electrical to both of these walls. Final step is to insulate and drywall.

**My question is, should I let the garage door installers install as it was before, with the garage door rail/track hardware bolted directly to the exposed studs, and then (in a manner I think will look less finished) drywall around all of the hardware mounting points?  OR, should I install the drywall first and have them mount the hardware to the studs with the lag bolts going through the drywall.**

If the latter, my plan would be to cut the pieces I need in advance for the garage door wall, and as they start taking down the old stuff, I'd quickly screw in place the new pieces. The goal is to have a clean look and to not have to cut a bunch of notches and holes and then mud over (or have to look at ugly) hardware cutouts in the gypsum board.

I've already mentioned to the installers I was planning to do this in the background while they tore out the old system, and they seem fine with it. But I also didn't get the vibe they were going to tell me which way was optimal.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would take their advice. I don't think I've ever seen a door mounted over drywall. For one thing, the brackets aren't sized for that (though they may have enough adjustment range to work). For another, **most installation manuals call for flat 2x4 lumber installed over the standard wall framing**, bringing the hardware mounting surface above the level of the drywall. This gives a good termination for the drywall and resolves the matter from the start.

The primary issue was raised in comments: If the drywall isn't initially crushed by bolt tension, it'll eventually disintegrate, and you'll be left with a floppy disaster waiting to happen. On your car.

Then, I doubt that either the manufacturer of the door or the installer will honor any warranty claims with drywall behind the hardware, and for good reason. Something as heavy as an overhead door should be mounted to framing.

Comment: @Martin - Talk to the installers if you're still unsure. You don't want to sacrifice your warranty for aesthetics. It makes the most sense to not sandwich the drywall and you can always "pretty it up" later.